# Android Studio Chipmunk removes all resources. Why?

Tags: android-studio

I use the latest version of Android Studio and faced an issue with removing unused resources under `Right click->Refactor->Remove Unused Resources`.

The issue is that it removes almost all resources when I only want to remove unused ones.

Why does the Android Studio removes used resources too?

Comment: I encounter that too ...

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue after updating to Android Studio Chipmunk + Gradle Plugin to 7.2.0.

Comment: @Menos exactly the same versions use I and face that issue

Comment: I am having another problem, but it is also related with string resources. I can not access library string resource from AS Chipmunk. When I open resource file, I can verify the string resource is in there but AS can not import...

Comment: @AlperÖzaslan did you clear the cache of AS and invalidate the ongoing session (File ->Invalidate Caches)?

Comment: i had the same problem on Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 14, 2023